# Issue with Payment Information

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, template, payment

I have a custom payment module, I am storing certain data in the `AdditionalInformation` field.

I want this data then displayed inside the Payment Information block from an admin view.

To do this I want to replace the file:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml
with 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/MYTEMPLATE/payment/info/default.phtml

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a module to use a custom admin theme (this way you could also make changes to any other adminhtml files without further work).

To do so follow this tutorial here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates

You could then place all your overriding template files in your new custom theme.

Comment: I tried using this solution but it has not worked, followed the instructions but viewing a customers order is still showing me the default block

Comment: From your question it looks like you've tried to place your new template file at: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/MYTEMPLATE/payment/info/default.phtml

When it should be:

app/design/adminhtml/default/MYTEMPLATE/template/payment/info/default.phtml

Comment: If following the method as I'd linked to I mean.

Comment: Brilliant! I had moved my files into the default directory but hadn't then created the "template" directory. Thanks

Comment: No problem Sam.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are 2 ways to do that:

1. Rewrite the block and call $this->setTemplate($relativePathToTemplate) in the block's constructor (not the best way).
2. Use an layout update and change template using the layout update. This is the best solution in terms of the code and design, but sometimes it doesn't work, so you have to rewrite blocks.
   Both solutions assume that you have create your own custom module to perform the required modifications.